# "Visibility: Hidden" Elements causing white space/scrollbar to appear

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where elements with `visibility: hidden;` still take up space, even with `max-height: 0;` set, causing the scrollbar to appear on the right.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umrgdve1/5/) example

```js
function next(id) {
    // list of screens
    screens = ["main-screen", "input-screen", "questions-screen", "results-screen", "compare-screen"];

    // hide current page, display next page
    document.getElementById(screens[id-1]).classList.toggle("hidden");
    document.getElementById(screens[id-1]).classList.toggle("visible");
    document.getElementById(screens[id]).classList.toggle("hidden");
    document.getElementById(screens[id]).classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100vh !important;
}

.screen {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-family: 'Work Sans';
}

.no-height {
    max-height: 0;
}

.visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.75s linear;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.75s linear;
    max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container center">
        <!-- 1. Main Title Screen -->
        <div class="screen main-screen visible" id="main-screen">
            <p>Find your Archivibe</p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="1" onclick="next(this.id)">Begin</button>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('input-screen').style.display='none';">Remove element</button>
        </div>

        <!-- 2. Input details -->
        <div class="screen input-screen hidden" id="input-screen">
            <h2>First, some info about yourself</h2>
            <div class="form-div">
                <form>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="region" class="form-label">Region</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="region">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="gender" class="form-label">Gender</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gender">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="age" class="form-label">Age</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" min="1">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="2" onclick="next(this.id)">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example, removing the hidden element with the conveniently placed button (reduces) the scrollbar length. In my local workspace this would remove the scrollbar entirely, solving the issue.

Are there any workarounds for this without using `display: none;`? Since that would invalidate my fade in transition which I would like to keep. Thank you!

Comment: It is not removing the scrollbar for me when i click on the given button in my local setup. What I can tell you is that, the scrollbar is because of the `100vh` height you have given to the container div here. Considering browser will assign default margins to your body, 100vh for the div will make it overflow the screen. Try giving `margin: 0` to your body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example I have tried to solve the problem by using `overflow: hidden;`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

    
.hidden {
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default margin on the body element is wrapping your 100vh element so you get a scrollbar as the height will exceed 100vh.

As standard practice when starting a project, it is always advised to include styling which removes default browser styling (called reset.css).

One way to fix the issue is to remove the body margin, then let  flexbox handle your `.screen` heights.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```